# How to make a JavaScript 'while' loop more elegant?

Tags: javascript

I've made a JavaScript 'while' loop to keep adding a random number from 1 to 10 to an array until the random number is 9 or 10.

```
function random() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (10)) + 1;
}

var array = [];
var element = 0;
while (element < 9) {
    element = random();
    if (element < 9) {
        array.push(element);
    }
}
console.log(array);
```

I have two questions.

1. How can I make the 'while' loop more elegant - without using (element < 9) two times?
2. How can I do this in a more elegant way, without using a 'while' loop?

Comment: You definitely want a `while` loop because you're doing something while a condition is true. Try `while( (element = random()) < 9) array.push(element);`.

Comment: @Santi They generate a new random number inside the loop so it's needed for this specific algorithm

Comment: @AndrewLi I noticed this and deleted my comment, though I suppose I would have just re-ordered the `random()` and the `.push`, initializing `element` as `random()` instead of `0`. **EDIT:** Seems cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ suggested the same thing as me, though Niet's answer is likely best.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That's an even better alternative to what I suggested. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That's exactly what I was looking for - perform the assignment and check in one step. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, you can initialise `element` with a random value to begin with:

```
var element = random();
while (element < 9) {
    array.push(element);
    element = random();
}
```

This gets rid of the inner `if`.

To answer your second question, it doesn't get more elegant than this really. If you really want to use something else, you could use a `do-while` by changing around your code but really it's the same thing.

---

An even better alternative (I credit @NiettheDarkAbsol) for this, is to perform the assignment and check in one step:

```
while ((var element = random()) < 9) {
    array.push(element);
}
```

You eliminate the need to even declare it outside, or call `random()` in more than one place.